# How to understand if I have a failing ssd or logical errors because of the problematic enrypted swap partition?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, ssd, swap

I'm with brand new nvme SSD. I also have it fully encrypted, drive, home and swap (swap seems to come by default) 
I had two occasions where I had to do hard reset and after EACH the system was either in emergency mode or mounted as read-only.
First time I reinstalled clean, and just 1 day after that the read-only thing happened not long after hard reset. Luckily I managed to fix it with fsck this time.

But if that is going to happen that often obviously this is not good enough solution.

The first thing I would like to check is if it's failing ssds or just logical problems because of the hard resets and encrypted swap, which seems to cause problems from my short research.

So how to do that?

Comment: Check the SMART data.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie, how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: See this Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1